# Running editbin.exe on TeamCity build server with only MSBuild tools?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, build-server

Is it possible to get editbin.exe installed on a build server (running TeamCity 9.*, although I don't think that's particularly relevant) so that we can modifiy the TSAWARE flag of a C# exe after it's built?

It appears that our only option is to take a code-based approach (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vclinkertool.terminalserveraware.aspx), and I'm not even certain that's a possibility since it appears to just use a .Net wrapper for the C++ linker, which is the whole problem here. If I could do that, I could just set up the project to set the linker option, but since we're using C#, there is no C++ linker.

I'm fairly certain that, even if it worked, copying editbin.exe from a developer workstation isn't permitted by the EULA, and we'd rather avoid needing to install VS (properly licensed of course) on the build server.

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual Studio Express. This edition comes with the C++ Tools.
Don't know if this is 100% compliant with the eula.